# Validating reCAPTCHA v3 in Django

Tags: python, django, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

In reCAPTCHA V2, I could verify in the views.py itself. However in V3 I don't know how to proceed. Now I'm using it in development with 127.0.0.1.

First I have generated the site key and the secret key.
In settings.py I have added secret key, 
`GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY = 'my_secret_key_here'`

Then in my signup.html I have,
`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=my_site_key_here'></script>`

Unlike previous there is no < div > tag to add the checkbox. The script itself is rendering the recaptcha symbol in the side of my browser.

My question is,

1. *How can I validate using **grecaptcha.execute***.
2. *Do I have to add the script with my site key to every page I want to protect from spam or is there any simple way*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add it to every page that has a submit form. The validation still happens in the view.

This library seems to do the heavy lifting to make integration easy - https://github.com/kbytesys/django-recaptcha3.

Answer (score 0):

this article looks help your problem: [How to implement google recaptcha v3 on your django](https://blog.ihfazh.com/how-to-implement-google-recaptcha-v3-on-your-django-app.html).

The summary:

1. call the execute method, this will return token that you need to verify in your backend.
2. You can save it somewhere in your form
3. send the token when submitting form
4. verify the token in your view

> Do I have to add the script with my site key to every page I want to protect from spam or is there any simple way

Exactly, you need to add the script on every page you want to protect from spam.